# Jquery how to find floating elements in DOM?

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, clearfix

Jquery how to find floating elements in DOM?

```
 float: left/right
```

Clearfix is related to element float. That is not needed in our case. How to find which elements floating in DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` and call the `css()` method to get the value of the `float` style. For instance, this will find all divs with `float: left`

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('float') == 'left'
})
```